# Printing to ubuntu client via network, using php that reside in windows 7 webserver

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows, php

I plan to change my windows 7 client to ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  The client has a local printer (Epson LX-310) that is used to print an invoice in web app environment built using apache with php (the web server is still win 7 machine).

The problem is, I already setup samba and already can print a page test from the Web Server (win 7), but somehow my web app can not print to the local printer in the ubuntu 14.04 client.  The printer in linux machine also already shows in webserver network folder and the share name is the same as windows client's name which is 'epsonlx'.

I already make sure that the ipaddress, workgroup name in Samba, and the printer name in ubuntu are the same as my windows client's configuration.

I use this php code to print from the web server to network client:

```
fwrite($handle, $Data);
fclose($handle);
copy($file, "//192.168.1.9/epsonlx");  // printing
unlink($file);
```

This code work OK when the client is another windows machine.  Is there any idea how to make this work to print on a client with ubuntu 14.04?

Many thanks.

UPDATE

OK this is first testprm:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf 
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384) 
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated 
Processing section "[printers]" 
Processing section "[print$]" 
Loaded services file OK. 
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE 

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions 

# Global parameters 
[global] 
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu) 
server role = standalone server 
map to guest = Bad User 
obey pam restrictions = Yes 
pam password change = Yes 
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u 
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* . 
unix password sync = Yes 
syslog = 0 
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m 
max log size = 1000 
dns proxy = No 
usershare allow guests = Yes 
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d 
idmap config * : backend = tdb 


[printers] 
comment = All Printers 
path = /var/spool/samba 
create mask = 0700 
printable = Yes 
browseable = No 


[print$] 
comment = Printer Drivers 
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

Change Guest OK = YES on both [printers] and [prints$]:

Run again testprm:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf 
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384) 
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated 
Processing section "[printers]" 
Processing section "[print$]" 
Loaded services file OK. 
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE 

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions 

# Global parameters 
[global] 
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu) 
server role = standalone server 
map to guest = Bad User 
obey pam restrictions = Yes 
pam password change = Yes 
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u 
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* . 
unix password sync = Yes 
syslog = 0 
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m 
max log size = 1000 
dns proxy = No 
usershare allow guests = Yes 
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d 
idmap config * : backend = tdb 


[printers] 
comment = All Printers 
path = /var/spool/samba 
create mask = 0700 
guest ok = Yes 
printable = Yes 
browseable = No 


[print$] 
comment = Printer Drivers 
path = /var/lib/samba/printers 
guest ok = Yes
```

my latest smb.conf file as follow:

```
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
workgroup = MSHOME

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
passdb backend = tdbsam

obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

It still can't print.  :-(

EDIT: it work.  Turn out WORKGROUP name in SMB.CONF is WORKGROUP and I have to change it to MSHOME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things you could try:

- 1) check out the output from `testparm` on the linux machine.
- 2) run `copy sometextfile.txt //192.168.1.9/epsonlx` in cmd on windows
- 3) adding `guest ok = yes` and/or `force user = guest` to smb.conf
- 4) Do 1) and 2) again

If that does not show you your error, post the output of the above, and I'll refine this answer

Comment: many thanks. will try that next week weekend when there is not many transaction. will report it back here.

Comment: 1) and 2) are non-intrusive tests. Run them, and update the info in your question

Comment: Hi there.  The first time I run copy anyfiles.txt \\192.168.1.9\epsonlx it give access denied.  Change the guest ok = yes windows does not complain but it still does not print.

Comment: Never mind.  It work.  Turn out the workgroup name in SMB.CONF is wrong.